# How to apply web socket to all clients and all components in React?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, django-channels, web-frontend

so I try to create websocket like this code in First Component :

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Routes from './components/routers/Routes'    
function App() {
   const ws=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/");
   


   useEffect(() => {
   ws.send("some message");
   ws.addEventListener('message',(event:any)=>{
    console.log('message listened!')
   })

   }, []);



   return (
    <>
     <FirstComponent/>
   </>
  )
 }

 export default App;
```

and second component code is:

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Routes from './components/routers/Routes'    
function App() {
   let stid:string|null=localStorage.getItem('stationid')
   const ws=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/");
   


   useEffect(() => {
   ws.addEventListener('message',(event:any)=>{
    console.log('message listened!')
   })

   }, []);



   return (
    <>
     <SecondComponent/>
   </>
  )
 }

 export default App;
```

the backend written by Django and use channels for Web Socket.
how I can send message from a client and receive message in all connected clients to Web Socket ??

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by creating a group in the consumers class when socket connection is opened .
yours consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
class myConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
        async def connect(self):
            path_components = self.scope["path"].strip("/").split("/") #assuming websocket url is "ws/app/<stationid>/"
            id = path_components[-1]
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                id, #Id decides which all channels you want to add in a group. you can use stationid as your group name .  
                self.channel_name
            )
            await self.send_group("hello!!" ,id ) #sends message to all channels of group
            await self.accept()
        async def send_group(self, message, group):
        # Send message to a specific group
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                group,
                {
                    'type': 'chat.message',
                    'message': message
                }
            )

        async def chat_message(self, event):
            # Receive message from group
            message = event['message']

            # Send message to WebSocket
            await self.send(text_data=message)
```

In the frontend

```
const { id } = useParams(); // asuming ur url localhost:5173/app/stationid/
const socket = new WebSocket(
      `ws://localhost:8000/ws/app/${id}/`
    );
    socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket connection opened");
    };

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log("Message from server:", event.data);
      // recieve all messages here . you can make use of useEffect hook to update UI every time a message is received . 
    };

    socket.onclose = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket connection closed");

    };
```

make configurations accordingly